# Angle between a point and $z$-axis in the view where $x = y$

Tags: 3d, angle

I am trying to find the angle between a point and the $z$-axis in the view where $x=y$.

For example: a point $C = (-24, -24, -118)$ as illustrated in the next picture.

[C in 3D space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUpMo.png)

how to find the angle shown in the picture below:

[The angle needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ8bo.png)

PS. My background is not mathematics. An example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use dot product by vectors $\vec u=OC=(-24,-24,-118)$ and $\vec v=(0,0,1)$ that is

$$\cos \theta=\frac{\vec u\cdot \vec v}{|\vec u||\vec v|}\implies \theta = \arccos \frac{\vec u\cdot \vec v}{|\vec u||\vec v|}$$

Note that in this way we find the angle measured from positive direction of z axes. The angle indicated in the picture is its complement $180°-\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind please elaborate by applying the equation to this example? (my background is not mathematics)

Comment: @M20 Aren't you aware about dot product?

Comment: I tried this with python and I got arccos (-118/118) => arccos(-1) ... that's why I asked for an example.

Comment: @M20 In this case $u\cdot v = -118$ and $|u||v|=2\sqrt{3769}$

Comment: @M20 You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***:

Imagine you draw a perpendicular line to $xy$-plane from point $C$. If that line meet $xy$-plane at $D$, then the angle you are looking for is $\angle DOC$. and $(OD)^2=(-x)^2+(-y)^2=2x^2$. Now you can find $\tan (\angle DOC)$.